# Why does AWS Lambda function log in CloudWatch but doesn't show console.log output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using CloudWatch from the AWS console and my Lambda function has a log group and log stream and I can see the recent invocations, however, the only thing that shows up in the logs is Start, End, and Report Request ID as shown below:

```html
START RequestId: fe8ca243-288e-48f1-b585-c5d84bfb1bd7 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: fe8ca243-288e-48f1-b585-c5d84bfb1bd7
REPORT RequestId: fe8ca243-288e-48f1-b585-c5d84bfb1bd7  Duration: 2.71 ms   Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB  Init Duration: 147.61 ms
```

Lambda Function:

```html
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ddb = new aws.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log("event: ", event);

    const tableName = process.env.TABLE_NAME;
    const region = process.env.REGION;
    
    console.log("table=" + tableName + " -- region=" + region);

    aws.config.update({region: region});

    // If the required parameters are present, proceed
    if (event.request.userAttributes.sub) {

        // -- Write data to DDB
        let ddbParams = {
            Item: {
                'id': {S: event.request.userAttributes.sub},
                'username': {S: event.userName},
            },
            TableName: tableName
        };

        // Call DynamoDB
        try {
            await ddb.putItem(ddbParams).promise()
            console.log("Success");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        }

        console.log("Success: Everything executed correctly");
        context.done(null, event);

    } else {
        // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
        console.log("Error: Nothing was written to DDB or SQS");
        context.done(null, event);
    }
};
```

Why can't I see the console.log output?

Comment: It can be because you may not have deployed the changes that you have made in AWS console editor and you are testing it from the testing tab which is runs your code the last deployed code. Or double check the logs maybe it is the logs from previous invokes because it works just fine for me (actually now I am working on lambda function myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be because the default logger's level is set to ERROR and dropped all the INFO logs. You'll need to lower that to INFO to see all of the logs in the "Test" window. At least that is what I found in Python:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```